# angularJS $http.get() success callback not be called on cross domain

Tags: angularjs

I am developing a small application use angularJS. The html pages are local file which will not deploy on web server. I defined a service module which will call the remote webapi to get the json data, however my success callback not be invoked.

```js
 $http({ method: 'GET', url: remoteServiceUri }).
 success(function (data, status) {
 var response = data;
 }).
 error(function (data, status) {
 var error = data;
 });
```

it always call into the error method. how can I resolve this issue please?
I can confirm that the service api work fine, as I tried deploy the page and webapi on the same site, in this case, it works.

is this caused by the cross domain or any configuration required?
Thanks.

Comment: does the remote service reply to the preflight OPTIONS request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure your remote web service to handle the preflight OPTIONS request.

Your web service must add the following headers to the response of the preflight OPTIONS request as well as the actual request:

```
{
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Expose-Headers": "Content-Type",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type"
}
```

You can find details about what which headers are required, and what do they mean here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: Thanks. It works after updating the webapi to support CORS.  I updated the web.config to append:


<httpProtocol>
         <customHeaders>
            <!-- Adding the following custom HttpHeader will help prevent CORS from stopping the Request-->
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>

Comment: You're welcome. But, as Yair said, for dev purposes you could always use a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache, you could use proxypass to redirect requests. This way your angular app talks "locally" with your apache server, and it will pass the request to a different domain.

For example, in your httpd.conf set:

```
ProxyPass /foo http://foo.example.com/bar
```

In your angular app call

```
$http({ method: 'GET', url: "/foo/action" }).then(...);
```

Your apache will translate "/foo/action" to "http://foo.example.com/bar/action".
Bye bye cross domain issues!

For more info, see [apache proxy module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html)

Comment: Hey @Yair , I think your solution is the best way to do it !!
But i Don't find the httpd.conf file on my project ( Apache on Ecplise ) do you have an idea how to find it ?

Comment: You should look for it in the folder where apache is installed,  search the entire computer if you must.